# Как спарсить json-ld обьект не скачивая всю страницу?

Tags: python, json, парсер

Есть следующий код на python.

```
import extruct
import requests
import pprint
from w3lib.html import get_base_url
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
r = requests.get('https://avtoinstrument.kz/p58052466-podemnik-dvuhstoechnyj-380v.html')
base_url = get_base_url(r.text, r.url)
data = extruct.extract(r.text, base_url=base_url)
pp.pprint(data)
```

Вопрос:
Возможно ли как-то остановить загрузку, после того как получили json-ld обьект чтобы не загружать весь исходнй код страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Можно. Используйте [Streaming Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests).

Например:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/stream/20', stream=True)

for line in r.iter_lines():
    # filter out keep-alive new lines
    if line:
        decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8')
        print(json.loads(decoded_line))
```

Скачиваете порциями, копите их и проверяйте пришли ли уже нужные вам данные:

```
import extruct
import requests
import pprint
from w3lib.html import get_base_url

url = 'https://avtoinstrument.kz/p58052466-podemnik-dvuhstoechnyj-380v.html'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

all_data = bytearray()

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if not line:
        continue

    # Копим данные, что приходят порциями
    all_data += line

    # Предполагаю, что на странице использует эта кодировка
    text = all_data.decode('utf-8')

    # Пробуем найти
    base_url = get_base_url(text, r.url)
    data_json = extruct.extract(text, base_url=base_url)

    # Если нашли
    if data_json:
        break

pp.pprint(data_json)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что это не совсем обычный json, json-ld. Данный вариант просто json библиотека не распознает. ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: @Иван, разве? Json-LD ведь совместим с обычным Json. И пример в ответе с json именно пример, тут ведь вам нужно работать с `line`, что является массивом байт. Если вы вставили свою ссылку и запустили код, то не должно у вас работать, т.к. тот сайт вернет HTML, а JSON

Comment: Поидее да, но в данном примере по моей ссылке этот парсинг не проходит,, с обычным json без проблем.

Comment: Задача и есть из html достать json-ld, не трогая по возможности html, на сколько это возможно.

Comment: @Иван, давайте еще раз. В цикле line будет возвращать куски из URL, например `<html>`, после '<head>', и так до конца. Ваша задача копить эти куски и искать в них ваш JSON-LD, после выйти из цикла

Comment: @Иван, окей, напишу подробнее в ответе. `extruct.extract` работает только с строками или еще с байтами? Для чего нужен get_base_url? Написал пример по вашим данным, возможно понадобится допилить. Судя по коду extract, если тот ничего не найдет, то вернет пустой словарь, https://github.com/scrapinghub/extruct/blob/master/extruct/_extruct.py#L16. Так что, условие с `if data_json:` правильно отработает. Да и от get_base_url не должно быть сюрпризов

Comment: lxml.etree.ParserError: Document is empty

Comment: @Иван, в какой функции эта ошибка? get_base_url? extract? Предполагаю, что в extract, т.к. в нем вызывается код parse_xmldom_html, а он вызывает `lxml.html.fromstring`. Вызывайте extract с параметром `errors="ignore"`: `data_json = extruct.extract(text, base_url=base_url, errors="ignore")`

Comment: Добавил в код еще pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)

Comment: всё что выдало { 'json-ld': [],
  'microdata': [],
  'microformat': [],
  'opengraph': [],
  'rdfa': []}

Comment: @Иван, замените `if data_json:` на `if data_json and data_json['json-ld']:` . Такое ощущение, что придем в итоге, к тому же, что и было -- правильно разберется целый html

Comment: Спасибо бро, я модифицировал немного код и все стало как надо, респект.

Comment: @Иван https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers